# Whose body was in the gator pit?

Tags: time-travel, deja-vu

In the magnificent but flawed film *Deja Vu* when Doug arrives at Carroll's hideout there seems to be a body the alligators are chewing. Whose body was it and in what timeline did it get there?

I have read this theory [on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0453467/faq) saying it can't be his partner:

> It is not Agent Larry Minuti. Carroll Oerstadt killed and burned Larry Minuti in the bayou but then dumped him in the river to make the death look as a result of the ferry explosion, a similar MO to what happened later to Claire Kuchever. Evidence supporting this theory: when Agent Doug Carlin is investigating the bayou scene in the present, he mentions nothing about the body found in the gator tank. Plus, why bother burn Larry Minuti if Carroll Oerstadt is going to feed him to the gators anyway. More on this theory: in the beginning of the movie, when Doug Carlin hears a similar ring tone to his own device coming from inside a victim's body bag, that was Larry Minuti in that body bag. He's a colleague of Doug Carlin and probably has a similar work cell (with a similar ring tone) that he uses on the job.

Comment: When Doug suggest that they should try to send him back, he states "What if we already did this" and the movie shows various hints at this, one of them is the "_YOU CAN SAVE HER_" on the fridge, the way the bomber talks on his confession some sort of(writing from memory) "_If you try to stop it, you will make it happen_", etc. I found the movie interesting due that implied several unsuccessful attempts to stop the bombing. So it's his partner, sent by an attempt to change the past by the paper note. can't anwser your "in what timeline?"  and **this is just my opinion** and all from memory.

Comment: It's his partner who got the pushed note and went to investigate. He is killed, burned and fed to the gator. No one had traveled back to the past as of yet.

Comment: Ah thanks , i also like the interview scene where carroll is surprised as he recognises doug as someone who previously tried to stop him and he killed

Comment: @howler when you include a quote from an external source you should cite the source, and if it's long enough put it in a quotation block, as I have done in this post.